# infinite dimensional representation of a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

When $H$ is separable infinite dimensional,$K(H)$ has no finite representation.Do there exist other non-unital $C^*$ algebras such that their representations cannot be finite dimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Any simple infinite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra (that is, "most" of them in the sense that these are precisely the ones people study a lot) does not admit a finite-dimensional representation.

Comment: Of course. Say $M_2 (\mathbb C)\oplus C_0 (\mathbb R) $.